# How to describe instance specific instance in Policy

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a policy to restrict users to view only specific instance in AWS EC2 console. I have tried the below policy and it still showing me all my available instances so I am wondering where did I do wrong on my JSON policy below. Thank you

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:DescribeInstances/instance-id"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In looking at [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), the `DescribeInstances` API call does not accept any `Conditions` to limit the results.

Therefore, users either have permission to make that API call (and hence view all instances), or you can Deny them from being able to make the API call. There is **no ability to control which instances they can include in their request**.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with John.

A slightly different way to go about this is not with policies and restrictions but filtering via Tags and filters on the console.

Not exactly what you want but if you only people to see the ones they should. Tag them and send get the link like

https://ap-southeast-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=ap-southeast-1#Instances:tag:YourTagName=AllYouCanSee